# How to store text file on h2 database using Java and JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, file, jdbc, h2

I'm trying to store the contents of a text file onto a database. The text is no more than 1000 characters long. How do I do this?

Comment: Just confused as to how I should go about doing this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To save content of Text file into Database.

1. Create a table with `CLOB`
2. Use `java.io.Reader`  to read the text file
3. Use JDBC API (PreparedStatement) to execute INSERT statement.

> ```
> String sql="INSERT INTO TableName (clobCol) VALUES (?)";
> PrepareStatement ps=connection.prepareStatement(sql);
> ps.setClob(1,readerObject);
> ```

Comment: Just InputStream? Googling around I get C# results which imply that the steps are much more complicated, which is actually what's confusing me!

Comment: No, a `Reader`, you are dealing with character data.